# Generating a random number with specified bit length?

Tags: java, android, random, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to make a function that can generate a random number and specify how many bits the random number can be.

More specifically, I am trying to generate a number that could either be 8, 10, or 12 bits long. This bit amount is specified by another variable.

I then want to represent this number as a hex in string or as an signed and unsigned integer in decimal. I think i can just use the various Integer.toString methods for that part.

How would I go about generating specific bit-length random numbers in Java?

So far, I have this function skeleton in place:

```
public static String generateQuestion(int numBits, int taskType){
    String questionStr = "";
    String questionVal = ""; // This is the string hexadecimal version of the randomly generated number
    // TODO: Code to generate random value based on numBits
    

    switch(taskType){
        case 0: // Hex to Decimal
            questionStr = "What are the signed and unsigned values for the " + numBits + "-bit value " + questionVal + "?";
            return questionStr; // Return the constructed string
        case 1: // Signed Decimal to Hex
        case 2: // Unsigned Decimal to Hex
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected Question Type: " + taskType); // In case the task type is something other than the 3 possible question types
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need cryptographically secure numbers or merely good distribution?

Comment: I don't need secure numbers. I just need something very simple that has a decent range and randomness. As for the link, I saw it before posting this but I don't think it deals with the specific bit requirement I have. It generates number within a range, but I don't know how I can set the range to match bit length.

Comment: Perhaps  could create a max_var for each specified bit length?

Comment: To generate a number with 8 bits, use 2^8, 10, 2^10, 12, 2^12, isn't that literally the definition?

Comment: Ah yes that could work. I was wondering if that only applied to base-10 but I can just generate it as a decimal and convert to hex later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a new instance of `java.util.Random`, preferably only one for your entire app.

Then, you  can invoke `.nextInt(x)` on it, where x is the upper bound (exclusive). So, if you want a 4 bit random number, you'd call `.nextInt(16)`, or if you find it more readable (it turns into the exact same bytecode), `.nextInt(0x10)`, which generates a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 16 (exclusive), so, from `0000` to `1111`.

To find the '16', it's just `1 << (bits-1)`. e.g. `rnd.nextInt(1 << (12-1))` will give you a 12 bit random number.

Numbers just are. An `int` has no notion of hex or decimal or binary. That's a thing you choose when you print it. `String.format("%x", 10)` will print `A` for example.

Comment: Ah nextInt() is just what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Just one question, how do I create a global instance of util.random in an android project?

Comment: Just make a static field, I guess.

Comment: Gotcha. And how would I get this rng to create negative numbers? Would I keep the same code but present it as a signed integer? 

I'm having an issue where it's only ever making positive integers using toString(x, radix: 10)

Comment: add or subtract, then. To generate a number between `[X, Y)` is done with: `.nextInt(Y-X)+X`. This works even if X (or Y!) is negative.

Comment: So if I wanted to generate a random number but with a specified number of bits would I do rnd.nextInt(1 << (numbits - 1)) + someNum?

Comment: It becomes quite strange once you speak of 'so many bits of randomness', but then plus a certain number. But, yes, that'd do it.